# Why is Java pass by value only?

Tags: java, pass-by-value

So here is another worthy downvote question.

I understand that Java IS pass by value and what this means and how it works. So this is not another can you explain what pass by value is. I am more curious as to WHY Java does not include pass by reference? I would imagine this would be useful? It would also be helpful to know to cement the reasoning in my head....

I hate 'it is because it is' scenarios surely the equivalent of 'because I said so'. So does anyone have an answer as to why Java only includes pass by value?

Comment: The additional complexity and confusion outweigh the benefits.

Comment: I don't think the question is "downvote worthy", but could you specify why you believe this is a disadvantage?

Comment: It isn't 'because I said so'. It is because Jim Gosling said so.

Comment: Guido - I guess you lose some functionality by doing so?

Comment: @Danrex note my answer which was hastily downvoted well before completion.

Comment: It wasn't me Necro... I thought your answer was helpful

Comment: Speculation: It's the simplest solution that could possibly work. Look at languages that allow either (like C#) how many times have you seen code that either uses th ref or out keywords? Almost none, and even when you do, you should almost always read it as "This function has more than one return parameter, and I couldn't be bothered to wrap it, also no anonymous classes or dynamic yet, or I don't understand the concepts", rather than "This method will do something useful and/or destructive to the object graph you provide".

Comment: Ok Mikkel thanks. So it's Java keeping a tight control on things it seems.

Comment: posting the essence of my answer here as a comment: In sum, deeming a language as "call by value" or "call by reference" is not very meaningful. The correct characterization is, whether a language allows automatic copying of data to prevent modification by callee, and whether a language allows creating pointers to allow a callee to modify primitives. Java doesn't allow either, and C++ allows both.

Comment: It's simpler than that. I think that for less advanced programmers the way Java does it is simplest to understand, when you're programming in C# and you see the `ref` or `out` keyword, you always need to figure out what it does. I have actually seen code that takes a parameter by reference and the first line of the method, just creates a new one. This creates an application which is next to impossible to debug (particularly if that object is a LINQ2SQL Entity), unless you want to manually step through all of it.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke replying here: that sounds like Java. The behaviors are: CALLER: Object p = new Object(); foo(p);, CALLEE1: void foo (Object p) { p.mutate(); }, CALLEE2: void foo (Object p) {p = new Object();}, CALLEE3 (C++ reference): void foo (Object & p) {p = new Object();} and possibly others. The differences are in automatic copying, automatic pointer creation and dereferencing, and there are enough differences in behavior that describing languages absolutely as "call-by-value" and "call-by-reference" is not very helpful.

Comment: Additionally, the JVM implementation of method calls is dramatically simplified by using a stack-based pass-by-value model.

Comment: @necromancer There is no automatic copying, automatic pointer creation, or automatic dereferencing. Saying it's not very helpful is simply wrong. Here is a Fidle that demonstrates the difference: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y5cGoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O'Reilly's Java in a Nutshell by David Flanagan puts it best: "Java manipulates objects 'by reference,' but it passes object references to methods 'by value.'" This was a design decision by Java. When you pass objects around, you are still manipulating the same underlying object as they all reference the same memory location. So I'm not sure what specific scenario you are thinking about that you can't do with the existing Java mechanisms.

Comment: While this is the only answer which isn't factually wrong, it doesn't really address the OP's question which is *why*.

Comment: The only thing you can't explisitly do is create the equivalent of ``int & x``, where in two separate places in the program can assign to the same *raw* ``int`` variable and have the changes propigate. You can of course get the same effect by placing the ``int`` into some container object and passing that object around, but you can't do it with just a base ``int`` (or ``double``, ``bool``, etc).